# Fetching google sheets data from firebase "Billing account not configured" even if it's google api

Tags: firebase, google-sheets, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to fetch some data from a google spreadsheet. According to the firebase pricing it says that cloud functions are limited to Google services which means that this should work. However when I try to fetch the data I get the the error:

```
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND spreadsheets.google.com spreadsheets.google.com:443
at errnoException (dns.js:28:10)
at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:76:26)
```

I am trying with the following code:

```
export const fetchExcel = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => { 

const query = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/hidden/od6/public/values?alt=json"
https.get(query, resp => {console.log (resp)});
 });
```

so I am not making an api call to a non-google service yet somehow I believe it's blocking me. How else can you do it?

Comment: Where is the documentation for the spreadsheet API you're trying to invoke?

Comment: I tried following the following link: https://coderwall.com/p/duapqq/use-a-google-spreadsheet-as-your-json-backend

Comment: That doesn't look like official product documentation to me.  Have you tried using the spreadsheet API formally documented here?  https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/

Comment: I have not, it doesn't seem correct to me as it seems that I need to authenticate with oauth? I just want to fetch a spreadsheet and not have my users log in in order to do that...

Comment: I believe it does need some for of auth to work.  Here's an example: https://gist.github.com/CodingDoug/ffc4f050cc489a0280eb7f4cbe36af07

Comment: (The point is - if it's not a documented Google API that presents no potential for abuse, then you can't invoke it without a payment plan.)

Comment: Okay I will have to try that, however following the example I get the errors:
2339[QF available]: Property 'sheets' does not exist on type 'typeof " on the line const sheets = google.sheets('v4')

Comment: If you're running into a different problem, then please ask a different question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a payment plan required, Cloud Functions can make outgoing HTTP requests to APIs under control of Google.  Typically these are well documented APIs, and are protected from abuse.  It's worth noting however, this does not necessarily include anything in the google.com domain.  An API has to be specifically whitelisted for use without a payment plan.

If you run into a formal Google-controlled API that is not whitelisted, please [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/) to have that evaluated.